# Using pytorch Autograd on both images axis

Tags: pytorch

I would like to use autodiff since I have heard many great stories about it. However, I want to check if
it is even possible what I want.

Given a function that returns an image X (generated by one single input image).. I want to compute the
x- and y-directional derivative. Normally I would use a kernel method, but I want to see if it is possible with this autodiff.

I understand that autodif is based on the Jacobian, and since I only have one input for my function.. it will only calculate
the derivative based on that variable. Hence, I expect that it will not be able to do these directional derivative.

Is this true? Or is it possible in another way?

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that autodif is based on the Jacobian

This was what I thought at first, but actually it is backward mode automatic differentiation (AD).
I created an [algorithm in Python for how AD works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63983200/5884955).

You just work on a level of the objective function, also called loss function or cost function or error function.

So you write your objective function to capture the x and y derivatives as well. You can always have the main loss function `l1` and add `loss = l1() + lx() + ly()`.